# Screen goes blank after GRUB loader

Tags: system-installation, boot

Everytime I choose to boot to eOS,screen goes blank most of the time after GRUB loader. No splash screen is ever displayed. Everytime I need to reset my laptop 3-4 times to get to lock screen of eOS. What is causing this problem and how should I resolve it. I have newly installed eOS and it is fresh. To make sure nothing gone wrong during istallation I installed eOS again and removed previous installation. I have Windows 7 32 bit on dual boot. And I use eOS 3.2 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

When you turn your computer on, press the <kbd>esc</kbd> key repeatedly after the bios screen until the grub menu comes up, use the arrow keys to highlight elementary os, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot command. Delete the words 'quiet splash $vt_handoff' from the line near the bottom that starts with 'linux' and press <kbd>f10</kbd>. This won't change it permanently and now you should see the error that is causing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you encrypt your disk during the installation? Because I have and every time I boot the screen goes black, but as soon as I press arrow-key-down or -up I can see the password prompt and enter the it. After that eOS continues to boot.

Comment: Would have add this as comment, but I have not enough reputation..